# Is there a tool to take a block of text and turn it into Java StringBuffer code?

Tags: java, string

I have several blocks of text that I need to be able to paste inline in my code for some unit tests. It would make the code difficult to read if they were externalized, so is there some web tool where I can paste in my text and it will generate the code for a StringBuffer that preserves it's formatting? Or even a String, I'm not that picky at this point.

This seems like a code generator like this must exist somewhere on the web. I tried to Google one, but I have yet to come up with a set of search terms that don't fill my results with Java examples and documentation.

I suppose I could write one myself, but I'm in a bit of a time crunch and would rather not duplicate effort.

Comment: Use Denis' answer, or just use an editor macro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood it correctly, any text editor which supports regexps should make it an easy task. For instance `Notepad++` - just replace `^(.+)$` with `"\1"+`, then copy the result to the code, remove the last `+` and add `String s =` to the beginning :)

Comment: This is what I ended up doing. It would have saved me some time to have a proper tool since I had hundreds of things to copy and paste, but it appears such a thing doesn't exist.

Comment: For hundreds of things it would be easier to create a simple Java class to do the work..

Answer (score 0):

If you want to externalize then, use a properties file or something like that to read the text.

If you are looking for a simple tool to break up your text into concatenated strings that are joined together by stringbuffer then, most modern IDE will help you do it automatically. Here's how.

1. Copy the block of text in the IDE
2. Surround it in double quotes and assign to a String type variable. (This step may not be required)
3. Enter carriage returns wherever you want to wrap the text to next line and the IDE will automatically break the literals, concatenate them using double quotes "" and add them together
4. All modern compilers will internally convert "addas" + "addasfdas"  literals to a String using StringBuffer.

Answer (score 0):

The squirrel SQL client has a function called convert to string buffer it works nice.